# Pandas not recognizing NaN as null

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have a DataFrame, a portion of it which looks like this:

[image]

I read in the file using this line of code:

```
df = pd.read_table(oname,skiprows=1,sep='\t',usecols=(3,4,5),names=['year','month','snow_depth'])
```

When I call df.isnull(), I get False for each cell when the NaN should come up as True by default, I believe. Does anyone have an idea why this isn't getting picked up on?

EDIT: Results of df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 360 entries, 516 to 875
Data columns (total 3 columns):
year          360 non-null int64
month         360 non-null int64
snow_depth    360 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 11.2+ KB
```

Comment: Can you post the output to your question the output from `df.info()`

Comment: @EdChum Absolutely. <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 360 entries, 516 to 875
Data columns (total 3 columns):
year          360 non-null int64
month         360 non-null int64
snow_depth    360 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 11.2+ KB

Comment: @EdChum Now I'm guessing it's because its type is an object.

Comment: This means it thinks its probably a string, also I asked if you could edit the info into your question, the reason is because the formatting get lost in comments. What does `df.loc[867,'snow_depth']` show as the dtype?

Comment: @EdChum Reads out as ' NaN'

Comment: Could you try adding to `read_table` the param `na_values=['NaN']` to see if this fixes it, or you could do `df.replace('NaN', numpy.NaN)`

Comment: @EdChum I added a space between the first quotation and NaN and it's working now. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Ah I see the problem so did you try `na_values=[' NaN']` or did you use replace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your data had `'NaN'` values as `' NaN'` so you can add as a param to [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table), `na_values=[' NaN']` and this will add this to the default list of values to treat as `NaN`.

Alternatively you can [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace) them using:

```
df.replace(' NaN', np.NaN)
```

Comment: This is what I did (just replaced it with 0 instead of np.NaN. Thanks!

Comment: OK, glad I could help, always useful to check the `df.info` and if you see `object` then you have to suspect a `str`, also you can upvote too ;-)

Comment: also not recognizing `nan`